# Separate compilation and linking again

Tags: c++

I'm reading about separate compilation and have a particular question about the process. Suppose I've written a function in a file called function.cpp. Similarly I declared that function properly in a header file function.h. Now a main program, called main.cpp, will use this function. First of all, to produce a working executable would it be enough to run

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
```

Does this command also compile the function.cpp file or do I have to run first

```
$ g++ -c function.cpp
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
```

Now suppose I make some changes in function.cpp. Which file has to be recompiled? Is enough to run

```
$ g++ -c function.cpp
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
```

will lead to an `undefined reference` **linker** error, because there is no definition of the symbols defined in `function.h` (if they are actually used in `main.cpp`).

In the second version you will need to include the object file generated by the first invocation in the second invocation as well.

In the third case, it depends: You will need to recompile `main.cpp` if the declaration of `function` changed (e.g. a change in the header occurred). Otherwise you just need to link the executable again.

`gcc` can generate Make rules when you run it with the `-MM` or `-M` on a source file. You can use this to generate a primitive `Makefile` and you really should use a build system.

Answer (score 2):

You should think about this about two separate tasks:

1. Compiling. This provides a *.o, this contains all the function/classes/methods/etc. that are defined in *.C file and the *.h included from it (defined, not just declared). For those things that have been declared, but not defined, there will be just a reference ("here's something I don't know")
2. Linking. This gets together all the *.o (and *.a and *.so or *dll if you have libraries to throw into the mix) and will try to match all undefined references with a definition in other *.o

So back to your question:

```
$ g++ -c function.cpp
```

This call to g++ compiles and gets a function.o

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
```

This call to g++ compiles (main.cpp) and links (main.o and ... You probably need to provide it with al the *.o relevant so that it knows where to look for undefined references).

So if you change function.cpp. You must at least

1. compile it to get a function.o
2. link the main program again so that the new definitions in function.cpp gets *linked* to the undefined references in the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile both with:

```
g++ -o main function.cpp main.cpp
```

I also recommend using -Wall